# Quadtree explanation and C implementation

Tags: c, algorithm, quadtree

Please explain quadtrees and provide simple code (preferably in C) for insertion and searching.

Comment: @dan_waterworth it will be quite nice in c.

Comment: @itay i tried googling but none of them were simple.may be i am not so good in algos.please try help me

Comment: Trees aren't really simple things.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Wikipedia has a good [article on quadtrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree). The quadtree section in [these slides](http://www.cs.sun.ac.za/rw712/2007/slides/quadtrees.pdf) is very good.

Here are some C implementations (found via [Googling for quadtree c -"c++" -"c#"](http://www.google.com/search?q=quadtree+c+-"c%2B%2B"+-"c%23")):

- http://hyantes.gforge.inria.fr/doc/quadtree_8c-source.html
- http://xw2k.nist.gov/dads/html/quadtree.html
- http://www.informatik.uni-ulm.de/acm/Locals/1999/src/quadtree.C

Comment: thnx marcog it was really useful