# Simply? Algorithm to find the part of game screen where there is no enemy

Tags: c, algorithm, ncurses

I have to to game for my school project.

I have a little problem with selecting part of game screen where there is no enemy.

Please see this screens, where i tried to explain a little bit.
[First screen](http://img64.imageshack.us/img64/8290/step1c.jpg)
[, Second screen.](http://img857.imageshack.us/img857/5951/step2l.jpg)

Ok, so I have player and i can move him around a play ground - from one border to second one.
And there is also an "enemy". The thing is, that I have to select area (divided by player line) where there is no enemy.

Does anyone know kow can i do that, with some reasonable speed and memory ( i don't have to declare char array[width_screen][height_screen]; )

Thanks

Comment: If this is homework, you should tag it as such. You should also post any code that **you** have tried.

Comment: I don't want code. I would like to get some idea how can I do that ;)

Comment: So you are coding Qix.  You need to use borders to define regions.  The write a routin within_region(region) to tell if the enemy is within that region.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

For a spatial search a nice option is to implement a [QuadTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree)

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544928/quadtree-explanation-and-c-implementation) question has some very helpful links on the subject.

Comment: +1 for Quad Tree, I'm currently studying under someone who studied under the inventor of this structure. Very neat structure

Comment: I'm not sure how quad-trees would apply here...?